# Evaluate $(-3)^2$, $3^2$ and $-3^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate each of the numeric expressions $(-3)^2$, $3^2$ and $-3^2$.

When I originally asked this problem I confused it with another problem...please help...thank you

Comment: Note that $-3^2$ is not $-3$ to the second power.

Comment: The question was not entirely clear, I've edited it. Did I get it right, Deriah?

Answer (score 1):

$3^2 = 3\cdot 3 = 9$

$(-3)^2 = (-3)\cdot (-3) = 9$

$-3^2 = -(3\cdot 3) = -9$

The crucial point is that in the expression $-3^2$, the minus sign is not included in the square (multiplication first).

Answer (score 1):

[1]. $(-3)$ to the second power: $(-3)^2=(-3)\times(-3)=(-1)\times(3)\times(-1)\times(3)=9$.

[2]. $3$ to the second power: $(3)^2=(3)\times(3)=9$.

[3]. $-3^{2}=-(3)\times (3)=-9$.

**Edit:**
Deriah, here is a response to your comment, to clarify number [1].

First of all, things you should know:

**A1**. In general, if $m$ is a number, then $m^{2}=m\times m$, so, if we let $m=-1$, then $(-1)^{2}=(-1)\times (-1)$. If we let $m=-2$, then $(-2)^{2}=(-2)\times (-2)$. If we let $m=5$, then $5^{2}=5\times 5$, and so on.

**A2**. In general, if $z$ is a number with a minus sign, then we can take out $(-1)$ from $z$. For example, if we let $z=-1$, then we have $z=(-1)\times 1$. If we let $z=-2$, then we have $z=(-1)\times 2$. If we let $z=-3$, then we have $z=(-1)\times 3$, and so on.

**A3**. The order of multiplication doesn't matter. For example, $-3\times 1=1\times(-3)$, $(-1)\times 5=5 \times(-1)$, $3\times 7=7 \times3$ and so on.

**A4**. In general, if $m$ is a number, then $(-m)\times (-m)=m\times m$, so, if we let $m=1$, then $(-1)\times (-1)=1\times 1=1$, if we let $m=2$, then $(-2)\times (-2)=2\times 2=4$, if we let $m=3$, then $(-3)\times (-3)=3\times 3=9$, and so on.

---

Now, responding to you comment, in number [1] we have $(-3)$ to the second power:

First of all, we use **A1**, so we have $$(-3)^2=(-3)\times(-3),$$

Next, we use **A2** to separate $(-1)$ from $3$, so we have

$$(-3)\times(-3)=(-1)\times(3)\times(-1)\times(3).$$

Then, we use **A3** to rearrange the numbers and multiply them,

$$(-1)\times(3)\times(-1)\times(3)=(-1)\times(-1)\times(3)\times(3).$$

Next, we use **A4** to multiply $(-1)\times(-1),$

$$(-1)\times(-1)\times(3)\times(3)=1\times 9.$$

And finally,

$$1 \times 9=9.$$

Alternatively, firstly using **A1** and then **A4**, we can calculate it quicker,

$$(-3)^2=(-3)\times(-3)=9.$$

I hope this helps. Do tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: please explain why you insert the -1's for the first problem to get the answer. I figure to "zero" it out to make the answer positive..??? please explain...thank you

Comment: Hi Deriah, I made an edit to my answer, please see the section under 'Edit'.

Comment: Thank you so much for the breakdown...I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome :)